# How to use tor with a program in shell?

Tags: tor

I am running [some programs](https://njw.name/getxbook/getxbook-1.2.tar.xz) in Bash in Ubuntu.

The programs download something using network sockets. Their README file says they can be used with tor, and I hope to change the external IP address by using tor with the programs.

I have tried to look up how to use tor with a program in shell on the Internet including tor's official website, but I haven't found a step-by-step explanation. Could you show me how to use a program with tor in Bash, and maybe also point to some resources for learning? (I have some but not much knowledge about networks and network programming)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`torsocks`](https://github.com/dgoulet/torsocks/).

Tor presents itself to other programs as a [SOCKS proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS), so any program that has built-in support for SOCKS can use Tor directly. For everything else, there are [numerous](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#CantSetProxy) [wrappers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/tsocks.1.html) that force network traffic to go to Tor rather than out the normal path.

The only thing that makes `torsocks` special is its focus on the nature of Tor, where you're concerned with privacy and such. Other SOCKS wrappers might let DNS requests bypass the proxy, for example, which leaks information about places you're visiting on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks. How is `torsocks` compared to `torify`?

Comment: @Tim: I haven't the slightest idea. I don't use Tor. I only answered because my Google-Fu is strong, I knew that Tor presented itself as a SOCKS proxy, and I knew what SOCKS is because I've been a network programmer for nearly a quarter century. :)

Comment: @Tim: I get a lot of useful-looking links in a [web search for `torsocks vs torify`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=torsocks+vs+torify).